# SQL Insert multiple rows with one INSERT

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, insert, psycopg2

I saw different questions dealing with inserting multiple rows in an SQL database using one insert. All of this questions have some recurrent format, where e.g. the row names stay constant. I'm interested in a more general case, where the columns change from row to row.
So my two datasets in column / row order would look like:

```
dataset 1: columns (ID, Name)
           values  (1, Alex)
dataset 2: columns (Name, Gender)
           values  (Bert, male)
```

And the desired table result looks like this:

```
ID    Name    Gender
--------------------
1     Alex
      Bert    male
```

Is it possible, to do those two inserts in one INSERT statement? Preferred answer is (but not limited to) postgreSQL interfaced by Python using psycopg2.

**Update:**
As I already got answers using the restructuring of the data, I want to emphasize the scope of my question. I am searching a way, to explicitly do something like:

```
Insert (ID, Name),(Name,Gender) values (1,Alex),(Bert,male)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table(Id, Name,Gender) VALUES (1, 'Alex', NULL), (NULL, 'Bert', 'male');`?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know the missing fields, only the fields which are already there.

Comment: But you can check table definition for column names

Comment: Yes I can, but in the worst case, I have to do the check for every single row, and reconstruct the table accordingly. Nevertheless, I am going to try that approach just to see what the overhead in my case is.